# yii2 How to insert multiple coma separated value in one particular field of a column of DB

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want save multiple values comma seperated in a particular field of the database in yii2. I have an array of names of images and want save them in a single field against its id.

> ("Khan",1," 'dfds.jpg','esz.png','hgfd.png' ","444")

Comment: U mean, u want to save string (which is your comma separated values) into database?

Comment: basically i want save three or four or whatever no of names comes in the array as separate string each name in a single cell not whole array as a single string.

Comment: So get interesting strings and serialize it?

Comment: you mean incode it in jason format and then save it

Comment: [Here you have](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Comment: get the array and implode it before saving it
$value=$post['image'];    
$img = implode(",", $value);
$job->image= $img;

Answer (score 2):

This is simple way to update table with known ID.

```
\Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update(
    'tableName',     
    ['field' => implode(', ', $imageNamesArray)], 
    'id=:id', 
    [':id' => $id]
)->execute();
```